# Do Titans only go for buildings?

Tags: titanfall-assault

In Titanfall Assault do the Titans only go after buildings such as turrets? None of mine seemingly want to try and stand on a hard point. The titans act as if they have two objectives fight with whatever is between them and the end turrets and fight the end turrets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the Thermal Scorch titan only Targets the medium and heavy turrets.  The rest of the titans will attack structures and base turrets these have the highest priority for them. The Titan appears to have a limited aggro ring and will not chase a foot target far.